# Change file creation date on Windows with PHP

Tags: php, windows

In php I can change the file *last modification* and *access time* arbitrarily with `touch()`

```
<?php
touch($filename,mktime(0,0,0,2010,1,10));
```

...but how to change the **creation time**?

*Why do I need this?* Well, If I retrodate a file or a directory's *mtime* to *before* their creation date, `explorer.exe` keeps showing me the more recent creation date instead.

Comment: I know it sounds kind of stupid... but you could always just copy the contents of the file into a new one and delete the old file. Though I would consider this method a last-resort because it's kind of sloppy - and I imagine it would be resource intensive as well.

Comment: @sammarks Actually I'm archiving stuff, and would like to put old stuff in a *old* directory, so that approach would require a mayem of system clock setting/resetting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mh, an unsatisfactory, but working, approach I found out about, is: using [**nircmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).
Nircmd is a 37kb utility. (redistributable, **closed-source**, freeware)

How to proceed:

```
<?php

$time=strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',$time);
$cmd=".\\nircmdc.exe setfilefoldertime \"$filename\" \"$time\"";
system($cmd);
```

Notes:

- **nircmdc.exe** is the command line version of nircmd (note the additional `c`  before `.exe`)
- **setfilefoldertime** is a nircmd sub-command, [it is documented here](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setfilefoldertime.html).

Still, I hope there is a COM or WMIC solution I couldn't find this time around.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the solution I had to resort to. As ZJR said, it is not satisfactory because it requires making a system call which is not ideal, and in my case, is horrible since I need to do it in a tight loop to process thousands of files, which makes it unstable at best.

Comment: Also, `nircmd` does not support files or folders with Unicode characters in their names.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one you can change file creation time and modify time

> [Win32 Console ToolBox 1.1](http://www.stevemiller.net/apps/)

```
exec('touch.exe /c /t "file.html" '. date('H:i:s'));
```

*nircmdc* -> is to powerful